# Alignment of elements of navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was building a website where I encountered a problem in navigation bar that the elements of navigation bar is not coming center aligned

HTML and CSS code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home    </a></li>
      <li><a href="#"> Marketing Services </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> IT Management Services </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Molex Portfolio  </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Employement Opportunities </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

My css Code is

```
body{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

h1{
    margin:1px ;
    color:red !important;
    text-align:center;
}

hr{
    border-color:red !important;
    width:50%;
}

a {
  padding: 0px 10px;      
}

#navigation{
    text-align:center!important;
    display: inline-block!important;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap ?

Comment: Only provide necessary code, as there is neither a `<hr>` nor a `<h1>` element in your HTML, there's no need for CSS declarations.

Comment: yes i am using bootstrap

Comment: I have hereby posted only a part of my full html code 
Other part have hr and h1 element

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to center the `ul` with `inline-block` style, try to change the it to be `block` instead

```css
body{

    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
h1{
    margin:1px ;
    color:red !important;
    text-align:center;
}
hr{
    border-color:red !important;
    width:50%;
}
a {
  padding: 0px 10px;

}
#navigation {
    text-align:center!important;
    display: block!important;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Marketing Services </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> IT Management Services </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Molex Portfolio  </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Employement Opportunities </a> </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>
```

Comment: Still this is doing nothing while i am applying

Comment: Is what you see when running this demo is what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this work...!

```css
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .navbar-nav {
      float: none!important;
      margin: 0 auto!important;
      display: table!important;
      table-layout: fixed!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <ul id="navigation" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"> <a href="#"> Home    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"> Marketing Services </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> IT Management Services </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Molex Portfolio  </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Contact Us </a> </li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Employement Opportunities </a> </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center align the text in the "li" just do

```
.navbar navbar-inverse{
 ul>li{
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```